# How to show lookup window in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

How would you do pop-up lookup window in Lightning, like in classic salesforce page if you have a lookup field in the visualforce page it adds the lookup button next to the inputField, in Lightning how would you do?

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the Library here: https://justinyue.wordpress.com/2016/01/23/migrating-visualforce-component-into-lightning-experience-world/

```
    <!-- Render Lookup Field -->
    <apex:outputPanel layout="none" styleClass="slds-lookup" id="divLookup" rendered="{!isLookup}" html-data-select="single" html-data-scope="single" html-data-typeahead="true">
        <div class="slds-form-element">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="lookup">{!$ObjectType[objectName].Fields[field].Label}</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon--right">
                <apex:inputField id="lookup" value="{!sObject[field]}" styleclass="slds-input" style="visibility:hidden" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var lkInput = document.getElementById("{!$Component.lookup}"); <!--Adjust for your needs -->
            lkInput.style.visibility = "";
            var lkSpan = lkInput.parentElement;
            var lkLink = lkSpan.querySelector("a");
            lkLink.style.visibility = "";
            lkLink.className = "";
            lkLink.innerHTML = "<svg aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"slds-input__icon\"><use xlink:href=\"" + "{!URLFOR($Resource.xxxxxx, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search')}" + "\"></use></svg>";
        </script>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

You will have to modify to use your merge variables